# flutter FCM notification foreground not working when I move logic into DDD Layers, how to fix it?

Tags: flutter, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I have below code which work perfectly on whole different situations such as

- When app is closed
- When app is opened
- When app is killed

```
  HomePageView.dart
  
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin fltNotification;

  void initMessaging() {
    var androidInit = const AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/launcher_icon"); //for logo
    var iosInit = DarwinInitializationSettings();
    var initSetting = InitializationSettings(android: androidInit, iOS: iosInit);
    fltNotification = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    fltNotification.initialize(initSetting);

    var androidDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails("1", "channelName");
    var iosDetails = DarwinNotificationDetails();
    var generalNotificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: iosDetails);


    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        fltNotification.show(notification.hashCode, notification.title,
            notification.body, generalNotificationDetails,payload: "Notification");
      }
    });

    // Didn't include background since it doesn't matter.
  }
```

So the above approach working but shouldn't be like above approach when my project DNA is like below :

- Domain Driven Development
- DI
- Clean Architecture and etc.

So I've migrated above code like below :

```
PushNotificationService.dart
abstract class PushNotificationService {
  Future<void> initialize();
  Future<void> subscribeToTopic(String topic);
  Future<void> unsubscribeFromTopic(String topic);
}

NotificationHandler.dart
class NotificationHandler {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    if (!kIsWeb && (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isAndroid)) {
      // Initialize the notification plugin
      var initializationSettingsAndroid = const AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/launcher_icon");
      var initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings();
      var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
          android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
          iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
      // await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      //     onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: selectNotification);

      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();
      }

      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        Get.snackbar("Hi", "Message", snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP);
        // Get.showSnackbar(snackbar)
        if (message.notification != null) {
          _showNotification(message);
        }
      });
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        _showNotification(message);
      });
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(
          _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    }
  }

  Future selectNotification(String payload) async {
    // Handle notification tapped while app is in the foreground

    _navigateToScreen(
        RemoteMessage(data: Map<String, dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(payload))));
  }

  Future<void> _showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'hooray_applications', 'hooray application public channel',
        importance: Importance.max, priority: Priority.high, ticker: 'ticker');
    var platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
    var title = message.notification?.title ?? 'No title';
    var body = message.notification?.body ?? 'No body';
    var hashCode = message.notification?.hashCode ?? 1;
    if (notification != null && android != null) {
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(notification.hashCode,
          notification.title, notification.body, platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: jsonEncode(message.data));
    }
  }

  Future<void> _navigateToScreen(RemoteMessage message) async {
    // Navigate to a specific screen when the notification is tapped
    // Handle the message data to navigate to the specific screen
  }

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
      RemoteMessage message) async {
    _showNotification(message);
  }
}

FirebasePushNotificationService.dart
class FirebasePushNotificationService implements PushNotificationService {
  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  final NotificationHandler _notificationHandler = NotificationHandler();

  StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>> _onMessageStreamController =
  StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>>.broadcast();

  StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>> _onResumeStreamController =
  StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>>.broadcast();

  StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>> _onLaunchStreamController =
  StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>>.broadcast();

  @override
  Future<void> initialize() async {
    await _notificationHandler.initialize();

    final initialMessage = await _firebaseMessaging.getInitialMessage();
    if (initialMessage != null) {
      _onLaunchStreamController.add(initialMessage.data);
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> subscribeToTopic(String topic) async {
    await _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(topic);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> unsubscribeFromTopic(String topic) async {
    await _firebaseMessaging.unsubscribeFromTopic(topic);
  }

  @override
  Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> get onMessageStream =>
      _onMessageStreamController.stream;

  @override
  Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> get onResumeStream =>
      _onResumeStreamController.stream;

  @override
  Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> get onLaunchStream =>
      _onLaunchStreamController.stream;
}
```

And eventually in DI I have below module:

```
Future<void> initAppModule() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(name: 'App-Public', options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  instance.registerLazySingleton<PushNotificationService>(() => FirebasePushNotificationService());
... Rest of codes
}
```

And in main.dart :

```
await initAppModule();
```

Above code work perfectly fine when app is killed or closed, but it won't work on foreground.

In general `onMessage` work in `HomePageView`, when I call it in presentation layer. how to fix this?